# Spring Roo 2.0.0.RC1: If i use my new language Addon in clinic example i get long stacktrace

Tags: spring-roo

**Test the new language addon**

I have now language Addon for german language and use ist in the clinic example.

After install new Language Addon i set

```
web mvc language --code de --useAsDefault in clinic.roo
```

before

```
web mvc language --code es
```

When i start the application all is in german. But in the command shell , where i started the application, a long stacktrace occur.

```
2017-03-08 12:00:53.176 ERROR - QP: - 9544 --- [nio-8082-exec-2] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8082-exec-2] Exception processing template "index": An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/index.html]")

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/index.html]")
        at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:667) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1087) [thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1061) [thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335) [thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189) [thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1257) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
...
```

only a short snippet from stacktrace.
Then i switch to spanish or english no stacktrace.
When i switch back to german the stacktrace occur.
Why? What is wrong?

I Test the new language in northwind-multimodule and get the stacktrace too
when i switch to german and after the menues don't work. I can add in url param lang=en and then the menues work again.

**Another Remark:**

The Label to switch languages in German all Labels ok (i have put them in message_de.properties) but in spanish or english the german label is not ok.

In the message Properties no language_Label property for german language, because in the I18N Plugin the message properties have no language_Label  for german.
The Plugin does not now anything about other languages.
I have manually add this entries and then all is ok.

**Ok i test it new only use normal message.properties and change name to message_de.properties.
Then build plugin new and when use the language in clinic example and get stacktrace:**

```
2017-03-16 12:48:26.179  WARN - QP: - 6104 --- [nio-8082-exec-4] o.s.w.s.r.WebJarsResourceResolver
      : WebJar version conflict for "momentjs/locale/de.js"

org.webjars.MultipleMatchesException: Multiple matches found for locale/de.js. Please provide a more
 specific path, for example by including a version number.
        at org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator.getFullPath(WebJarAssetLocator.java:259) ~[webjars-locator
-core-0.30.jar:na]
        at org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator.getFullPath(WebJarAssetLocator.java:200) ~[webjars-locator
-core-0.30.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.WebJarsResourceResolver.findWebJarResourcePath(W
ebJarsResourceResolver.java:108) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.WebJarsResourceResolver.resolveResourceInternal(
WebJarsResourceResolver.java:79) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.AbstractResourceResolver.resolveResource(Abstrac
tResourceResolver.java:46) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultResourceResolverChain.resolveResource(Def
aultResourceResolverChain.java:57) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.CachingResourceResolver.resolveResourceInternal(
CachingResourceResolver.java:78) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.AbstractResourceResolver.resolveResource(Abstrac
tResourceResolver.java:46) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultResourceResolverChain.resolveResource(Def
aultResourceResolverChain.java:57) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.getResource(ResourceH
ttpRequestHandler.java:432) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(Resourc
eHttpRequestHandler.java:333) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAd
apter.java:51) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [
spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970
) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring
-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar
:8.5.5]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spri
ng-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar
:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.j
ava:230) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
 [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-webs
ocket-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.j
ava:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
 [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(Resou
rceUrlEncodingFilter.java:53) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:10
7) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.j
ava:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
 [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:
208) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [sp
ring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy
.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:
262) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.j
ava:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
 [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter
.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:10
7) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.j
ava:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
 [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormConte
ntFilter.java:89) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:10
7) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.j
ava:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
 [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFi
lter.java:77) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:10
7) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.j
ava:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
 [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncoding
Filter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:10
7) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.j
ava:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
 [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomc
at-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomc
at-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [t
omcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-emb
ed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embe
d-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-
embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed
-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-embed-
core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-
embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [
tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomc
at-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-e
mbed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0
_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0
_121]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomca
t-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
```

Comment: Could you provide more specific stacktrace to be able to check the error? Regards,

Comment: I have put more stacktrace inside but i can't put the whole stacktrace it contains to muche characters.

Comment: I have now a Problem. When i can't change the Language to german the javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message come in english and i can't overwrite in message.properties.

Comment: Hello can anybody help with this problem?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could publish or provide the german language addon you have generated to be able to test it and try to find the cause of your problem. Even better would be if you would provide the project you have created or at least the log.roo file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have found a problem in the Thymeleaf layouts generated by Roo when the language is not English or Spanish, as well as the webjar of the moment.js library.

To solve it, you have to edit the layouts generated in your project in the folder *src/main/resources/templates/layouts* and find the following line:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/locale/es.js" data-th-src="@{/webjars/momentjs//locale/}+ ${#locale.language}+'.js'" data-th-if="${#locale.language} != 'en' and ${#locale.language} != 'es'">
  </script>
```

It seems the moment.js webjar contains two copies of all the locale related files, and the webjars resolver finds them and doesn't know which one to use. To solve it the path with the webjar version must be used. Also the URL is not well formatted. Replace the previous fragment with this one:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/locale/es.js" data-th-src="@{/webjars/momentjs/2.13.0/locale}+ '/' + ${#locale.language}+'.js'" data-th-if="${#locale.language} != 'en' and ${#locale.language} != 'es'">
  </script>
```

Comment: Hello  Thank you i will test it